# SQL-How to insert one value from one table to another but the data in another table should remain the same

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function, database-table

I have two simple tables:

- bazaa (ime VARCHAR(20),prezime VARCHAR(20))
- bazab (ime VARCHAR(20),prezime VARCHAR(20))

Let's say bazaa contains 1 ime and 1 prezime and bazab contains 2 ime and 2 prezime.

I want to insert values into bazaa and those values should also be inserted into bazab but it shouldn't delete anything or mess up the positions of rows.

I tried with some triggers from answers on other questions but it doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Insert into bazab select * from bazaa;
```

Comment: That is a simple solution but I need a function or trigger for automation